# Kendo UI Grid MVC5 ASP.Net - Strongly typed view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have recently started incorporating Kendo UI into my project.  I have a strongly typed view and wish to bind the Kendo grid to the appropriate View Model on the view:

```
@Model IEnumerable(Of IMS_2.Models.expenseclaims)
@Code
ViewData("Title") = "Index"
End Code

<h2>Index</h2>

<div>
@code
    Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("ExpenseClaims") _
     .Columns(Sub(c)
                      c.Bound(Function(x) x.ClaimDate).Width(140)
                      c.Bound(Function(x) x.Title).Width(190)
                      c.Bound(Function(x) x.Company)
              End Sub)
end code
```

Upon execution the code halts at the Grid statement with an exception:

> Method invocation failed because 'Public Function
>   Columns(configurator As
>   System.Action`1[[Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridColumnFactory(Of
>   GridColumnFactory(Of expenseclaims))) As
>   Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridBuilder(Of expenseclaims)' cannot be called
>   with these arguments:
>
> Argument matching parameter 'configurator' cannot convert from 'VB$AnonymousDelegate_2(Of Object)' to 'Action(Of GridColumnFactory(Of expenseclaims))'.

...which as a relative newbie has left me somewhat baffled.  My code is (I think) a direct translation of other examples I've seen in c# (see http://telerikhelper.net/2012/10/26/using-kendo-grid-in-asp-net-mvc-4-0/)

Expenseclaims is generated by the EF template and is defined as:

```
 Partial Public Class expenseclaims
        Public Property id As Long
        Public Property Title As String
        Public Property ClaimDate As Nullable(Of Date)
        Public Property Creator As Nullable(Of Long)
        Public Property Company As Long
        Public Property AdvanceOffset As Nullable(Of Decimal)   
        Public Overridable Property expenselines As ICollection(Of expenselines) = New HashSet(Of expenselines)
        Public Overridable Property companies As companies 
    End Class
```

Which is where I am stumped...Any help gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the @Model to @ModelType for VB.NET since @Model is for C#.

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of IMS_2.Models.expenseclaims)
```

Comment: For info - here is the article I've been following that explains use of a strongly typed view and grid:  http://telerikhelper.net/2012/10/26/using-kendo-grid-in-asp-net-mvc-4-0/

Comment: What does this IMS_2.Models.expenseclaims model look like?  Our issue may be there.

Comment: Thanks Piercove - I've added the expenseclaims definition to the original post

Comment: I just noticed that your model declaration is this: (at)Model IEnumerable(Of IMS_2.Models.expenseclaims), you should try this: @ModelType IEnumerable(Of IMS_2.Models.expenseclaims) in your original code since VB is differently written.

Comment: Ah yes - that makes sense.  Now I'm not seeing anything populated in the grid (or the grid being rendered at all).  Maybe this has now become a different issue and I should raise another question..

Comment: If you are not seeing the grid render, that means that validation has passed for the grid structure since the data is being loaded via an Ajax call.  If you have Firefox with the Firebug add-on (or look at a Console in IE) to check for JavaScript errors, that would be helpful.  I think though as far as the Model goes, I think that part is fixed and I updated the answer above.

Comment: Agreed - this has eliminated the bug that was the core of the question  - I've marked it as answered thank you.  A corollary is now the non-rendering grid which I will ask separately.